# Date object not returning correct time value

Tags: android

I am using below code to get the current time in specific format and then want to print the time stamp.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ms");
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    Date curDate = null;
    try {
        curDate = dateFormat.parse(formattedDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(Config.TAG,"curDate...... "+curDate);
```

but when I see the Logcat output "curDate....." is showing "Mon Jul 13 04:11:51 EDT 1970"
but in the above statement minutes are wrong.
but In my android device, time is showing as "04:40 AM".

I am unable to figure out why the above method capturing "29" minutes delay.??

Pl. let me know is that the proper way to do this.
let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's the "ms" part of your format string which is confusing things. I think that you mean "SS" instead. Also, given that you haven't got an AM/PM specifier, you probably want a 24-hour format instead of 12-hour:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
```

(Do you *really* not want the year, by the way?)

Comment: +1, although it is still strange that there is a 'delay' when using ms (which is actually minutes and seconds). I'm having a 15 minutes delay by the way

Comment: @Fortega: When you specify "ms" you're saying "single digit minutes and then single digit seconds". It's not a delay, it's simply parsing the value in a way you *really* don't want. I'd argue that it should barf given that "mm" and "ss" have already been specified, but that's a separate matter...

Comment: it's indeed some parsing problem. I was just curious what exactly goes wrong here. See my answer below for the explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jon's answer: an explanation for the problem:

if you try the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ms");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
Date curDate = dateFormat.parse(formattedDate);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
System.out.println(curDate);
```

it prints something like

```
3632
Thu Jan 01 00:13:32 CET 1970
```

This is because the parser threats the '3' as minutes and the '632' as seconds.
3 minutes and 632 seconds is 13 minutes and 32 seconds.